# attempt to reference field of non-structure array. matlab gui

Tags: matlab

AOA i m new in to use matlab i have some problem....... i have 4 gui in which one are my main gui and other are for text,image and audio browser...... individual these gui work properly and show result but when i run my main gui ..through push button i call my 2nd gui it will open .when i select text or image it will give following error..........

" **attempt to reference field of non-structure array.**

and following are code

```
[filename,pthname]= uigetfile('*.txt','File select text');
fullpathname = strcat(pthname, filename);
text = fileread(fullpathname);
set(handles.text3, 'String', text);
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

please help me.........

Comment: Is the error occuring on line 4? is `handles` defined?

Comment: yes error occur on line 4............and i didnt know where handles define.....but individual these GUI work perfect

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I try run the gui from command line, the error disappear. Maybe you can try **run the gui file from command input**.